# Link IBOutlet to both iPhone and iPad Storyboards

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, iboutlet

I am writing a universal application. As far as I can tell, it's not possible to use Interface Builder to link an IBOutlet, which is already linked to the iPhone storyboard, to the iPad storyboard?

What are possible workarounds for this? Should I just edit the storyboard via text editor?

It doesn't really seem sensible to have an IBOutlet for each device if it's the exact same element behaving in the exact same fashion.

Cheers-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be perfectly capable and able to add IBOutlet's to both an iPhone_Storyboard file and likewise the same IBOutlet's on an iPad_Storyboard file.  What does it appear to be doing, simply detaching your previous connection in the other Storyboard file?

I've done this on multiple universal applications without an issue.

Comment: Yeah I think it was just Xcode acting up. I restarted all my equipment and deleted all the cached stuff for my project and I was able to connect the proper outlets... Which is weird because I tried that already. Honestly, Xcode sometimes doesn't let me connect IBOutlets at all. Very buggy imo, I'm gonna file some bug reports when I finish my project. Thanks for that tip though, it helped.

Comment: No problem, glad it's working for you.  Often times I also have to close out of the project to have access to outlets.  Sometimes I can do a cmd+k (clean project), then cmd+b (build project), then go back into Interface Builder and also have access to those properties again.  At least it's working for you now!

Comment: @Doug, im having the exact same issue right now. My IBOutlet in iPhone simulator works fine. But in iPad simulator it's nil.

Comment: How exactly does one do this? What series of control drag operations will accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. My problem was that I forgot to make sure that the Custom Class of the UIView were the same in both the iPhone and iPad versions of the storyboard. After fixing that, Xcode instantly let me connect the outlets.